# how to get rid of this {{ user.id }} (curly braces) in vuejs while a page is in loading state

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using vuejs in my project and noticed that when a page is in loading state, I see something like this `{{ user.id }} {{ user.name }}` which is very annoying.
And after the page is fully loaded, I can see the `userId` and `user name` properly.

How to stop showing the these curly braces of vuejs in a page while it is in loading state?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a directive built for this purpose: `v-cloak`.  http://vuejs.org/api/#v-cloak

> This directive will remain on the element until the associated Vue instance finishes compilation. Combined with CSS rules such as `[v-cloak] { display: none }`, this directive can be used to hide un-compiled mustache bindings until the Vue instance is ready.

```css
[v-cloak] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div v-cloak>
  {{ message }}
</div>
```