# How to avoid {{expr}} flash to display on page before Vue.js take over?

Tags: vue.js

For example, I have somewhat large amount of spans (over 300+) in one page, each span has `{{expr}}` binding to display its content:

```
<span>{{expr}}</span>
```

Right after page loaded, the literal `{{expr}}` will flash to display on the page before VueJS takes over and display the real binding value. This looks bad to client, is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get rid of this {{ user.id }} (curly braces) in vuejs while a page is in loading state](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40428070/how-to-get-rid-of-this-user-id-curly-braces-in-vuejs-while-a-page-is-in)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

[`v-cloak`](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-cloak) is the HTML attribute you are looking for.

> This directive will remain on the element until the associated Vue instance finishes compilation. Combined with CSS rules such as `[v-cloak] { display: none }`, this directive can be used to hide un-compiled mustache bindings until the Vue instance is ready.

Comment: Very nice! Thanks.